# Get translation from another store

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to programatically send a custom email from admin and I need to add some strings before sending the email. I would like to translate these strings based on a language selected. I used the code below but it does not work, the string stays in English.

```
$localeInterface = $objectManager- 
>create('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface');

$localeInterface->setLocale('de_DE');
$localeInterface->setDefaultLocale('de_DE');

echo __('Some string');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate the string into another locale using `getDictionary()` function of `\Magento\Framework\App\Language\Dictionary` class as described follows:

```
protected $_dictionary;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Language\Dictionary $dictionary,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_dictionary = $dictionary;
    ...
}

public function execute() {
    ...
    $arrString = $this->_dictionary->getDictionary('de_DE')['Some String'];
    ...
}
```

In `$arrString` variable, you will get phrase in the source code as a key and the string translation as a value.

I hope it may resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes it solved my issue thanks a lot for your help !